# How to get highest number of sales in any 3 month period of the last year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table (simplified for this question) of items that are sold on given date, as follows:

```
item_id    sale_date
-------    ---------
  1        2017-01-01
  2        2017-01-14
  1        2017-02-02
  3        2017-03-03
 ...          ...
```

And would like to return the result: *the best sold item was #1 in the period Feb-Apr.*

The 3 month span is not a quarter, just any 3 month span in the last 1 year.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: If it's MySQL 8.0 you can use CTEs, something that makes life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date_add()` to calculate the begin and the end of the possible three month periods. Join them, so that the `sale_date` is in the period. Then group by the item ID, the begin and the end of the period. Order the result descending by `count(*)` to have the best sold items on top. Use `LIMIT 1` to only get the first record.

```
SELECT t.item_id,
       p.b,
       p.e
       FROM elbat t
            INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                               date_add(sale_date, INTERVAL -day(sale_date) + 1 DAY) b,
                               date_add(date_add(sale_date, INTERVAL -day(sale_date) + 1 DAY), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) e
                               FROM elbat
                        UNION
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                               date_add(date_add(sale_date, INTERVAL -day(sale_date) + 1 DAY), INTERVAL -3 MONTH) b,
                               date_add(sale_date, INTERVAL -day(sale_date) + 1 DAY) e
                               FROM elbat) p
                        ON p.b <= t.sale_date
                           AND p.e > t.sale_date
       GROUP BY t.item_id,
                p.b,
                p.e
       ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49343/27)

You maybe need some additional criteria for the `ORDER BY` as there can be multiple periods with the best sold item (because the periods overlap and of course because there can be items which were sold in identical numbers). Right now there's just any row with the maximum sales figure atop.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select *
  from (
    select item_id, count(*) as sales
      from my_table
      where sale_date > date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 month)
      group by item_id
    ) x
  order by sales desc
  limit 1;
```

Comment: Why the super query?

Comment: @Strawbery Because I didn't simplify it. I guess I tend to see the "big nodes" of the query and then just didn't realize in this case it could be reduced.

Answer (score -1):

Your question suggests that you are specifying the 3-month span.  If so:

```
select item_id
from t
where sale_date >= '2017-02-01' and sale_date < '2017-05-01'
group by item_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```